# How to search the same text in different Rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a search button, when I type in my TextBox and click the Button, it search in my "Brand" column in a DataGridView.
If I type `BMW`, the row gets selected, however if I have multiple `BMWs`, and click the button again, the other rows won't be selected:

```
string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            break;
        }
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting `MultiSelect` property to `True` and `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`, you can achieve it.

```
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect:
```

And one more thing, remove the `break` statement from your code as it breaks your loop when the first match is found. 
Please try this and let me know if any additional change is required in it.

```
if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
{
    row.Selected = true;
    //break; -- remove this one and try
}
```

Comment: Also, following this suggestion will require that `dataGridView1.ClearSelection();` be moved outside (before) the foreach-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove break statement from you're code. It won't continue to search after found one row if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample class that allows to search the content of a [DataGridView.Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows) collection, specifying the search criteria and a Column that is the target of the search.

The results of the search are cached, so the search is repeated only when the search criteria or the Column index change.

This class uses the [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1), which returns an object that allows to iterate a collection. The [MoveNext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) method is used to move the selection to the next element in the list of `DataGridViewRow` results.
When the last element is reached, the Enumerator is moved back to the first element using the [Reset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset) method + `MoveNext()` (`Reset()` set the enumerator to the *starting* position, before the first element in the collection, so it points to a null element;  `MoveNext()` then push it forward in the first position).

Initialize this class with the DataGridView object that is the source of the Rows collection:

```
var dgvSearcher = new DGVSearcher(dataGridView1);
```

To perform a search, call the public **`Search()`** method, specifying the search criteria (the partial content of a cell), the Column index and a parameter (`bool selectRow`) that indicates whether the Rows should be selected.
For example, search the string `"Some text"` contained in `Cell[1]` of any Row and select the Row:

```
dgvSearcher.Search("Some text", 1, true);
```

When this search is first performed, the first Row that satisfy the criteria is displayed in first position. If the search is repeated using the same criteria, the next Row is moved in first position and selected if specified.

A visual example of this behaviour:

[image: DataGridView Row Search class]

The **`DGVSearcher`** class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal class DGVSearcher
{
    DataGridView dgv = null;
    string m_SearchCriteria = string.Empty;
    int m_ColumnIndex = -1;
    IEnumerator<DataGridViewRow> m_enumerator = null;

    public DGVSearcher(DataGridView dataGridView) => this.dgv = dataGridView;

    private List<DataGridViewRow> cached { get; set; } new List<DataGridViewRow>();

    public bool Search(int cellIndex, string criteria, bool selectRow)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria)) return false;
        bool result = true;
        if (criteria.Equals(this.m_SearchCriteria) && this.m_ColumnIndex == cellIndex) {
            if (!this.m_enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                this.m_enumerator.Reset();
                this.m_enumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            SetSelectedRow(this.m_enumerator.Current as DataGridViewRow, selectRow);
        }
        else {
            this.m_SearchCriteria = criteria;
            this.m_ColumnIndex = cellIndex;
            result = RebuildCachedCollection(cellIndex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private bool RebuildCachedCollection(int cellIndex)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (cached.Count > 0) cached.Clear();
        cached = this.dgv.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                              .Where(r => r.Cells[cellIndex].FormattedValue.ToString()
                              .Contains(this.m_SearchCriteria)).ToList();
        if (cached.Count() > 0) {
            this.m_enumerator = cached.GetEnumerator();
            this.m_enumerator.MoveNext();
            SetSelectedRow(this.m_enumerator.Current as DataGridViewRow, true);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void SetSelectedRow(DataGridViewRow row, bool setSelected)
    {
        row.Selected = setSelected;
        this.dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = row.Index;
        if (!setSelected) this.dgv.CurrentCell = this.dgv[0, row.Index];
    }
}
```