# Conditional sorting for datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which I have a textbox to search for account name, i use string.contains and set the matching cell to the first displayed index, but i need the user to be able to see other cells that are matching too

```
 private void SearchAccountTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AppraisersDGV.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (AppraisersDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(SearchAccountTxtBox.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),)|| AppraisersDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(SearchAccountTxtBox.Text.Trim()))
            {
                AppraisersDGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I searched on SO but so far the only kind of sorting i saw was either ascending or descending

Comment: the header of your question says conditional sorting, but from the body of your question, I guess you want to display all rows which match a certain string, correct?

Comment: @tmlye yes, i figured it would need conditional sorting, in sql i just use the like operator, but i think its not efficient to be querying from the database everytime the text changes which is why i am doing it in c#

Comment: Try out the DGV-search class shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993753/7444103).

Comment: You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using datatable when populating data into Datagridview?

if that so, then try this one.

```
Dataview dvp = datatable
dvp.rowfilter = String.format("Column_name Like '%{0}%', SearchAccountTxtBox.Text)
Datagridview.datasource = dvp
```

I hope this one helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done winforms in a while, but something like this should work:

```
private void SearchAccountTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = SearchAccountTxtBox.Text.Trim();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in AppraisersDGV.Rows)
    {
        row.Visible = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue.ToUpper() || row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue);
    }
}
```

It hides all the rows which don't match the search term.